# Firestore Document does not maintain the order of keys in LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I have with me a List of Pairs which I insert into a LinkedHashMap and upload it to the Firestore document. However the key order in the Firestore Document does not match that of the LinkedHashMap.

Here's the code:

```
    Map<String, String> quesMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for(Pair<String, String> pair : quesAnsPairList){
        Log.d(TAG, "adding key : "  + pair.first);
        quesMap.put(pair.first, pair.second);
    }
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : quesMap.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();
        Log.d(TAG, key + " found");
    }
    //....
    visitorsCollectionRef.document(visitor_id).set(quesMap);
```

Comment: LinkedHashMap retains the order in which entries were added. What does the Firestore documentation say about ordering? What is the ordering of the original List<Pair>?

Comment: Where do you see this? In code or in Firebase Console?

Comment: @Steve11235 I did not find anything about ordering in firestore while adding fields to the document. We can however order the data while retrieving it from firestore. In the original list the data was as in the following order ['1a', '2a', '3a', '1',' 2', '11'], however the order of elements in the document field is ['1','2','11','1a','2a','3a']

Comment: I wish to know as to how I can implement ordering such that the data is retrieved in the same order in which I wish to write the data to the Firestore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot change that order of documents. I see that you are using `Strings` when ordering. Note, that when strings are ordered, are ordered `lexicographically`.

Let's take a simple example. For numbers, this is the normal order:

- 1308
- 1309
- 1310
- 1311

But for strings, this is the normal order:

- "1308"
- "1309"
- "131"
- "1310"

There is no operator in Cloud Firestore and as far as i know nor in most other databases that allow you to change this behavior. Instead, you will have to modify the data to get the behavior you want. So, store values that are in the order you need them when sorted lexicographically. For numbers you can accomplish that by padding them with zeroes:

- "0131" //zero added before
- "0132" //zero added before
- ......
- "1308"
- "1309"
- "1310"
- "1311"

Comment: And, if you use `update()` updated fields go to the bottom.

Comment: This lexicographic behavior is applied for nested object, too.